# How can I have dependent third-party library copied to target folder

Tags: build

I have a third-party, native library (API.DLL) that I use in my program. I have written a C++ wrapper (Wrapper.dll) for the API. My application (MyApp.exe) makes calls to methods in the wrapper. The MyApp project references the Wrapper project. When I run my application, I get a FileNotFoundException:  Could not load file or assembly 'Wrapper.dll' or one of its dependencies.

The problem is that API.DLL isn't found. When I build Wrapper, the Wrapper.dll and API.DLL files both get placed in the Wrapper\Bin\Debug folder. When I build MyApp, the Wrapper.dll file gets placed in the MyApp\bin\Debug folder, but the API.DLL file does not!

What is the correct/best way to get the third-party DLL in the application target folder when I build my solution?

Answer (score 1):

Add the file to your project, put it the root folder inside the project, make the solution Show All Files, then add it (if not already).

Then change the properties of the file (right click-> properties) to build action=None and Copy to output directory=always or newer (whatever you prefer).

The file will get copied when you build.

Comment: Add the file to the 'Wrapper' project, or to the 'MyApp' project? I was hoping that the 'MyApp' project would not need to know about dependents of the 'Wrapper' library.